# Set Position of Point Label in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: c#, .net

Using the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting library, the positioning of line chart **point** labels is pretty bad.

By default the labels sometimes are positioned on the line rather than above or below.

[image: label unreadable]

If the SmartLabelStyle is set on the series

```
series.SmartLabelStyle = new SmartLabelStyle()
{
    MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Top | LabelAlignmentStyles.Bottom,
};
```

The labels are no longer moved horizontally, but the higher point's label can be placed below while the smaller point's label is placed above!

[image: labels are layer confusingly]

Is there a way to explicitly place a point label?

Comment: You invoke the "I'm smarter than the smart label" mode with the PostPaint event.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for but unable to find myself.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished via the PostPaint event on the chart.
Some documentation and tutorial here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456612.aspx

A limited solution that worked within the constraints of my chart, that might be of some help for anyone who comes across this question.

```
chart.PostPaint += (sender, args) =>
{
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < args.Chart.Series[j].Points.Count; i++)
        {
            var point = args.Chart.Series[j].Points[i];
            var altPoint = args.Chart.Series[j == 0 ? 1 : 0].Points[i];
            var above = point.YValues[0] > altPoint.YValues[0] || (point.YValues[0] == altPoint.YValues[0] && j == 0);

            var pos = PointF.Empty;
            pos.X =
                (float)
                args.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.X,
                    point.XValue);
            pos.Y =
                (float)
                args.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.Y,
                    point.YValues[0]);

            pos = args.ChartGraphics.GetAbsolutePoint(pos);
            pos.Y += (above ? - 20 : 10);
            pos.X += -10;
            args.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawString($"{values[j][i]}%",
                new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10),
                new SolidBrush(_colorPallette[j]), pos);
        }
    }
};
```

[image]